# Which object in DateGeneration object when there are two short, long or combination in Schedule object for py QuantLib?

Tags: programming, quantlib

I'm pricing a vanilla swap. I have two stubs, front and back, and they can be short, long or a combination. In this case, what do I use in `ql.Schedule` object for `Rule` parameter? I use `ql.DateGeneration.Forward`, but I wasn't sure for two stubs. In the [QuantLib for python](https://leanpub.com/quantlibpythoncookbook/read) under Schedule Class, I didn't see for two stubs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to explicitly define your stubs with the firstDate and nextToLastDate.

```
effectiveDate = ql.Date(27,6,2020)
firstDate = ql.Date(15,12,2020)
nextToLastDate=ql.Date(15,12,2021)
terminationDate = ql.Date(2,6,2022)
frequency = ql.Period('6M')

schedule = ql.MakeSchedule(
    effectiveDate, terminationDate, frequency,
    firstDate=firstDate, nextToLastDate=nextToLastDate
)

dates = list(schedule)
for start, end in zip(dates[:-1], dates[1:]):
    print(f"{start.ISO()}, {end.ISO()}, {end-start} days")
```

2020-06-27, 2020-12-15, 171 days
2020-12-15, 2021-06-15, 182 dyas
2021-06-15, 2021-12-15, 183 days
2021-12-15, 2022-06-02, 169 days